# Поворот изображения за курсором js

Tags: javascript

Друзья - подскажите как реализовать такую анимацию

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BisYUJek43_-9E5TmeLENpvyx_S6lpJJ/view

Знаю что нужно использовать mousemove и делать rotateY но как это все собрать в кучу не хватает знаний ((

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PeVojE  так ?

Comment: Почти =) уже сделал проще немного

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно , готовый код

```js
const maxWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
const goldenRatio = maxWidth/2;
const maxRotate = 40;
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var position = event.screenX;
  const allImages = document.querySelectorAll('img'); 
    for(let i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
      allImages[i].style.transform = `rotateY(${(goldenRatio - position) *  maxRotate / goldenRatio}deg)` 
    }
})
```

```css
.gerb-blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .gerb-blocks-img {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .gerb-blocks-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="gerb-blocks">
  <div class="gerb-blocks-img">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg/2000px-Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gerb-blocks-img">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg/2000px-Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gerb-blocks-img">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg/2000px-Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gerb-blocks-img">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg/2000px-Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gerb-blocks-img">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg/2000px-Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gerb-blocks-img">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg/2000px-Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg.png" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ну, это совсем не то, что у Вас на видео: работает только при движении мыши в одну сторону и не поворачивает изображение, а просто сплющивает :((

Comment: @humster_spb  вот полный вариант в обе стороны поворачивает https://codepen.io/antoha-sozon/pen/EGxZvV